# Can I change the "redmine" interface elements with "visual studio" or another system?

Tags: redmine

I use
Visual Studio 2015

Can I change the "redmine" interface elements with "visual studio" or another system?

For example, for the "task creation form" I want to add "buttons" or additional "tab bar".
Can this be done by analogy with working with "Windows Form"?
I mean drag the button onto the form and add the code for the button.

PS
I start to study programming, I apologize if the question is inaccurate

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change Redmine UI, and add/remove new features, you would have to learn html/css, ruby, and Ruby on Rails framework.

Once you learn them, best way to modify Redmine is by making plugin which adds functionality you want, and preferably share that plugin with others via github and redmine's plugin registry listed here: [www.redmine.org/plugins](http://www.redmine.org/plugins)

In that sense, you can use Visual Studio, as code editor, or any other text editor, as long as they have nice syntax coloring, code indenting, and preferably function and variable name completion...